# Why does adding stylesheet to QListView change behavior that is not determined by the style sheet itself?

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, listview

I have a QListView to which I added line separators using the following stylesheet:

```
listView_->setStyleSheet("QListView::item { border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; }");
```

However something unexpected has happened - on single click on any item in the list, the data vanishes from the display. It comes back on a double click. This is quite weird I think. Why is this happening ?

Here is the QListView

[image: The QListView]

This is what happens as soon as I click on any item:

[image]

The data that has just vanished, comes back when I double click (instead of a single click - or selection action)

Why is this happening and how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each item in the view has states, for example a `selected` state represents an item that is currently selected. Now, if you look at the list without any stylesheet attached, you will notice that selected items have dark blue background and white text. However, when you are assigning this stylesheet

```
QListView::item { border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; }
```

you are in fact modifiing all states at once, including the selected state, which causes it to have the default white background along with the white text. For example, if you add another property:

```
QListView::item { border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; background:red; }
```

you will notice, that all items (both selected and not selected ones) will have red background. To fix the issue, you should specify that your stylesheet must be applied only to items that are not selected

```
QListView::item:!selected{ border-bottom: 1px solid black; padding: 2px; }
```